# Invalid text representation error when Laravel exist validation with postgres id field use UUID

Tags: laravel, postgresql

This is my table migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

class M2 extends Migration {
    private $output;

    public function up() {
    Schema::create('trantype', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
    });

    DB::table('trantype')->insert([
        ['id' => 'dddae2bf-407c-439a-83bd-7246727fe7aa', 'name' => 'Dana Masuk'],
        ['id' => '5ccaff7c-2210-4c22-bdd9-a645c6af4c5f', 'name' => 'Dana Keluar'],
    ]);
}
```

This is my model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TranType extends Model
{
    const TABLE = 'trantype';

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $keyType = "string";
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = self::TABLE;
    protected $fillable = ['id','name'];
    protected $hidden = [];
}
```

This is my validation inside controller:

```
$rules['trantypeid'] = 'required|exists:trantype,id';
```

When I run the code, it error when do validation with the following msg:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax 
    for type uuid: \"3333\"\nCONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...' (Connection: 
    pgsql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from \"trantype\" where \"id\" = 3333)",
"exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
"file": "/var/task/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
"line": 793,
"trace": [
```

This issue happen when I'm using Postgres DB, and run normally when using MySQL DB.
When I search this issue online, this issue happen because I use UUID for ID field.
So I have to cast the filter into string.

I have add casting in my model above:

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'string'
];
```

but it looks like this cast not used when Laravel doing validation.

Can someone help me for this issue?

Comment: There's no need to caste the id.

Comment: Also, what value as `trantypeid` you're passing? Looks like you're passing 3333 which is not a valid UUID and hence you're getting the issue. You should also add `uuid` rule to the validation: `'required|uuid|....'`

Comment: Hmm..
Yes I'm in purpose to send value 3333..
I want to check if the value should exist in DB, if not, validation will fail.

Ok i will try to add validation to check the value is valid UUID

Comment: You actually also found a bug in MySQL, there is no proper UUID validation for your input.

Comment: @OMiShah you are correct. When I put "uuid" validation, it check the value for valid UUID string first.
Then if value already valid UUID, it can check/filter into database without SQL error.

Comment: but the uuid you are sending to the endpoint is an integer in the example?

Comment: i would believe that validating the uuid to be a string would fix your problems 'required|string|exists:trantype,id'

Comment: @mrhn yes I purposely to send http request with value 3333, to know if server can block invalid data or not.

Comment: You can do that with 'required|string|exists:trantype,id'

Comment: @mrhn, it's better to use uuid validation rule instead of string when you're expecting uuid.

Comment: If I put "string" in validation: 'required|string|exists:trantype,id', postgres show error on SQL generated by Laravel:


"SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: \"ddt55\"\nCONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...' (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from \"trantype\" where \"id\" = ddt55)".


So I will stick with "uuid" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$rules['trantypeid'] = 'required|uuid|exists:trantype,id';
```

Because most SQL-engines leave validation to you, and *may* throw an error/exception.

> Where "may" means: when invalid input is given, even crashing could be possible.